# How to open a File from a defined Path with the Eclipse default open-Action (EclipsePluginDevelopment)?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a small Plugin. I need the following feature, but by reading the API, there was no help.
The plugin creates a eg.xml-File.
When i manually open the File (RightClick -> Open), Eclipse opens the JUnitView with the TestSuites (Its the correct content).
So, my plugin should do exactly this: Just show the eg.xml in the JUnitView.

Comment: There is no standard API to 'open a file in a view'. Exactly what view are you asking about? Use [Eclipse Plugin Spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy) to find out what its id is.

Comment: It's the JUnit View (where you can see your TestResults). The SurefirePlugin creates for eacht test class a new xml-File. So i have merged these Files to a single one.
If i doubleclick (or rightclick -> open or rightklick -> open with -> JUnitView), the XML is shown correctly in the new View.
I would like to adapt exactly this function.